# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, log4j

I am trying to use slf4j in an Maven project for logging. I'm getting the below error even after adding the slf4j-api and slf4j-simple dependencies in my pom file.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/log4j/or/RendererMap
at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.<init>(Hierarchy.java:97)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:82)
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:81)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.or.RendererMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more
```

Below is my pom file dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.1.2</spark.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
 </dependency>
```

Is there any other dependency I'm missed to add in the pom file?

Comment: Issue resolved by adding the below dependency to the pom file.        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an answer in case others are looking for solution.

Add the below dependency to the pom file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```